# R function finding dataframe rows with specific attributes

Tags: r, function

I currently have a large dataset for which I want to find total time spent at altitude and range of temperatures experienced. 
An example dataset is provided:

```
time<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
height<-c(10,33,41,57,20,27,23,39,40,42)
temp<-c(37,33,14,12,35,34,32,28,26,24)
practicedf<-data.frame(time,height,temp)
```

I want to calculate the total time spent above 30 m (height) and range of temperatures experienced at these altitudes. However, in my actual dataset the sampling frequency has resulted in a series of datapoints that skip over 30 m (i.e. going from 28.001 to 32.02 and never actually stopping at 30). Therefore I wanted to create a code that documented all of the dataframe rows that are below 30 m and also each time there is a gap between dataframe rows greater than one (to account for times when the data is above 30 m and then returns below 30 m, i.e. 27.24, 32.7, 45.002, 28.54) so I know to discount all points above the altitude I am targeting.
I've created the following function to carry this portion of my analysis out (pinpointing dataframe rows below 30 m).

```
pracfunction<-function(h){
    res<-as.vector(lapply(h,function(x) if (x<=30) {1} else {0}))
    res1<-as.vector(which(res == 1))
    res_new<-list()
    for (item in 1:length(res1)){
        ifelse((res1[i+1]-res1[i]>1), append(res_new,i), 
        append(res_new,"na"))
  }
  print(which(res_new != "na"))
}
```

I want the output to look like:

```
[1] 1 5 6 7
```

Since in the vector height, indices 1, 5, 6, and 7 have values less than 30.

However each time I run it with height as the input I receive integer(0) as the output. I'm pretty new at writing loops and functions so if anyone could provide input into what I'm doing wrong, or has a better way to approach this problem it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think it would help to show the desired output: for example, by adding another column to `practicedf` with some indicator variable. Also your code contains `x <= 20`, but you want heights below 30?

Comment: @neilfws I've added the above edits, let me know if the addition of the expected output helps!

Comment: Your sample data do not contain the situation you want to address *also each time there is a gap between dataframe rows greater than one (to account for times when the data is above 30 m and then returns below 30 m*

Comment: In base `R`, getting your desired output is very simple:

    `which( practicedf$height <= 30 )
    [1] 1 5 6 7`

Comment: Hi @vaettchen, I don't think I explained that portion well enough, I apologize! Essentially if I wear to plot height as a line graph and find the times it intercepts 30 (which would be something like 23 to 39) however you are correct I did include something in the other direction(returning from 39 to 23).

Comment: This is not in line with your desired output. Also, for the intercept you would need a pair of indeces in the height vector?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dplyr` to create a new column `low` indicating whether `height < 30`.

```
library(dplyr)
practicedf <- practicedf %>% 
  mutate(low = ifelse(height < 30, 1, 0))

   time height temp low
1     1     10   37   1
2     2     33   33   0
3     3     41   14   0
4     4     57   12   0
5     5     20   35   1
6     6     27   34   1
7     7     23   32   1
8     8     39   28   0
9     9     40   26   0
10   10     42   24   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand your intentions correctly but here is what I think you might be looking for. Start with an extended sample data.frame:

```
pd <- structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
      13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), height = c(10, 33, 41, 57, 20, 
      27, 23, 39, 40, 42, 10, 33, 28, 17, 20, 27, 23, 39, 40, 42), 
      temp = c(37, 33, 14, 12, 35, 34, 32, 28, 26, 24, 37, 33, 
      14, 12, 35, 34, 32, 28, 26, 24)), .Names = c("time", "height", 
      "temp"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then this function gives you the index of intercepts in a way that the value of every crossing the 30m line in either direction is given. I guess that's not exactly what you want but you can take it from here.

```
pf <- function( x )                                  # x is the data.frame
{
    res  <- ifelse( x[ , "height" ] <= 30, 1 , 0 )   # simplified version of your attempt
    n <- NULL                                        # initiate the index vector
    for( i in 1:( length( res ) - 1 ) )              # to accommodate room for comparison
    {
      if( res[ i + 1 ] != res[ i ] )                 # registers change between 0 and 1 
        n <- append( n, i + 1 )                      # and writes it into the index vector
    } 
    return( n )
}
```

With this, the call

```
pf( pd )
```

returns

```
[1]  2  5  8 11 12 13 18
```

indicating the positions on the height vector *after* the height limit of 30m was crossed, in either direction.